# Redirection to home page

Tags: forms

I am working on a Drupal site. I have put a "Create an account" block on one of my content pages. After the form is submitted the user is redirected to the home page. I want to reload the same page on submit. Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install this module http://drupal.org/project/login_destination

It is also possible to keep users on the currently visited page after logging in or out.

Hope it will match your requirement!!!

Comment: done it works for registration too..?

Comment: @Syed Hashim Now you've resolved this question, please check it off.

Comment: Bala yap checking for it. Thanks for your support bro

Comment: The login destination module (as its name implies) does not work for user registration.